# python: фреймворки для серверной части (для работы с запросами от клиента)

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, клиент-сервер

есть клиент, написанный на nodejs (react)

клиент посылает серверу запросы (через fetch) и файлы (через компонент Upload от Ant design)
сервер

сервер написан на pythonb обрабатывает запросы без сторонних библиотек из серии

```
# получить данные от клиента
def get_request_data():
    # получить размер входного буфера
    content_length = os.environ.get('CONTENT_LENGTH', 0)

    if not content_length:
        raise Exception('CORS req?')

    # считать данные из входного буфера
    buffer = sys.stdin.buffer.read(int(content_length))

    # преобразовать данные в формат UTF-8
    data = buffer.decode('utf-8')

    if not data:
        raise Exception('No input<POST> json!')

    return data
```

Подскажите, может стоит использовать какие-то фреймворки, которые прячут эту реализацию под капотом и в 1 строчку позволяют получать и json данные и файлы и отвечать клиенту без обвязки типа

```
        # передать сформированный ответ клиенту
        print('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8')
        print('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *')
        print('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS, POST')
```

Comment: Посмотрите FastApi

Comment: @Mike, я правильно понимаю, что клиент может быть на чем угодно, а это именно серверная честь клиент-серверного приложения, она не формирует страницу для пользователя, она именно работает с сервером (с БД, файлами и т.д.) и как-то общается с клиентом?

Comment: Есть два подхода, "старый", когда страница (html) динамически полностью формируется на беке и отдается. И "новый", когда у вас есть бек отвечающий только за данные, обычно отвечающий в json и клиент на js для браузеров и мобильные приложения. Первый в принципе быстрее в разработке если вы fullstack разработчик, второй более гибок, кроме web позволяет использовать других клиентов, в первую очередь мобильные приложения

Comment: когда клиент - это React приложение которое общается с сервером через некоторые запросы (через тот же fetch и сервер передает данные в виде Json, а клиент уж сам все делает для отображения) - это какой из двух подходов? второй?

Comment: да, второй. И касательно фреймверков большинство слишком тяжелы, так как рассчитаны для работы по первому подходу, содержат всякие шаблонизаторы и много другого, что не требуется при формировании json. Поэтому FastAPI, он как раз рассчитан в основном на отдачу ответов в json